# Aspect class code can't be interwoven with target class code in Rapier-LOOM

Tags: c#, aspect, rapier-loom

I wrote the aspect class and the target class 'using C# Visual Studio 2008.net' but every time I run the application to interweave them only the target class executed but I can't execute aspect class i tried to attach references to rapier-loom and tried to uninstall rapier-loom and install it again but the same problem occurs....what is the problem ?

#### this is the aspect class:

```
using System;

using Loom;

using Loom.JoinPoints;

namespace HelloAspect
 {

    public class TraceAspect : Aspect
    {
      [Loom.JoinPoints.IncludeAll]
      [Call(Advice.Around)]

      public T Trace<T>([JPContext]Context ctx, params object[] args)
      {
        Console.WriteLine(ctx.Instance + "." + ctx.CurrentMethod.Name + " called");

        ctx.Invoke(args);
        return default(T);
      }
    }

 }
```

#### this is the Application method:

```
using System;

using Loom;

using Loom.JoinPoints;


 namespace HelloAspect
 {

    class Program
    {
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
          string name;
          Console.Write("Your name: ");
          name = Console.ReadLine();
          TraceAspect aspect1 = new TraceAspect();
          Target target = Loom.Weaver.Create<Target>(aspect1);
          target.Hello(name);
          Console.ReadLine();
       }
    }
 
 }
```

#### the Target class is:

```
public class Target
{
    public virtual void Hello(string name)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello {0}!", name);
    
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you implicitly call the `ToString()` method of the Target class from your advice method via the `ctx.Instance` call. This will lead in a **endless recursion** because ToString is also interwoven by the advice method.